# Filter Arrays from JSON with Space values

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, json, filtering

I want to filter my JSON with a form input.

**My Filter:**

```
var as = $(data).filter(function (i,n){return n.name == getname});
```

the "getname" comes per get from a HTML Form.

**Sample JSON:**

```
[
 {"name":"name1 addition","date":"01.02.2017"},
 {"name":"name2 addition","date":"05.02.2017"},
 {"name":"name3 addition","date":"05.03.2017"}
]
```

My Problem is if i use a textbox and the "name" has a space in it, it doesnt work cause the space. Can i fix this somehow?

Comment: You can `trim` string to get rid of extra spaces.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `test()` function together with `RegExp`.

```js
var json = [
 {"name":"name1 addition","date":"01.02.2017"},
 {"name":"name2 addition","date":"05.02.2017"},
 {"name":"name3 addition","date":"05.03.2017"}
];

function filter(json, name){
  var reg = new RegExp('name', 'g');
  var result = json.filter(v => !reg.test(v.name));
  console.log(result);
}

filter(json, 'name2 addition');
```

Comment: @Justin Taddei Thank you for your edit, but it wouldn't work if I would accept your review :(

Comment: I don't understand. As it is now the name parameter is not used.

Comment: @JustinTaddei `name` is an argument of the function, not object property (:

Comment: argument . . . that's what I meant to say. You have written `function filter(json, name) { . . . }` however `name` is never used. Is that intentional?

Comment: @JustinTaddei `name` is used my friend. The user passes the `name` variable in function arguments, for example `name2 addition`. Then, it is being used inside the `new RegExp`, to make a new regexp object. And inside the `filter()` function we will test every object from json if it fits the `test()` function.

Comment: oh i think my question is wrong, i want it the other way, not sorting out the one who is filtered. I want to show the one who is filtered.

Comment: @JustinTaddei That's right. I thought something else, but Patrick told me how it has to be made :) Anyways - thank you :)

Comment: @Kinduser oh thanks! i should employ myself about RegExp!

Comment: @JustinTaddei There are different approaches, this is only one of them :)

Comment: `reg` is the same has `/name/g` right? How does that filter it? My mind is about to explode :)

Comment: @JustinTaddei Yes this is exactly the same. How does it filter? Pretty simple. If `test()` function returns `true` (regexp has matched given element) - it filters this element from array.

Comment: @KindUser I must be missing something. That works I just don't get how because all the json objects have 'name' in the name (name1, name2, and name3) so is seems like the filter should match all of them.

Comment: @JustinTaddei They all have **only** `name` key. But we only match that objects, which `name` key has value of `name2 addition`. And there's only one there with this value.

Comment: @KindUser `v.name` === `name[1-3] addition` over the three iterations `json.filter` makes for the three elements in the array, right? (By the way, I'm not questioning your code I'm just trying to understand it)

Comment: @JustinTaddei `json.filter` deletes only these objects, which returned `true`. They return true if the `test` function matched anything. Matched - true. Not matched - false.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/136798/discussion-between-justin-taddei-and-kind-user).

Answer (score 0):

I've been playing with @KindUser 's answer for awhile and found that it returns every even element in the `json` array. I made some changes to their answer that fixes the problem.

Try this and see if it works better for you:

```js
var json = [
 {"name":"name1 addition","date":"01.02.2017"},
 {"name":"name2 addition","date":"05.02.2017"},
 {"name":"name3 addition","date":"05.03.2017"},
 {"name":"name4 addition","date":"05.02.2017"},
 {"name":"name5 addition","date":"05.02.2017"},
 {"name":"name6 addition","date":"05.02.2017"}
];

function filter(json, name){
  var reg = new RegExp(name, 'g');
  var result = json.filter(v => reg.test(v.name));
  console.log(result);
}

filter(json, 'name4 addition');
```